# How do I turn a contract into a client?

Tags: client-relations

I am starting up my own media company, where I will be focusing mostly on creating video content for clients. I've had contract with a few pent-up clients that seem promising, but it's hard to reel them in. How do I help things move forward without being insensitive?

Comment: This might be better asked on https://startups.stackexchange.com/ . A media business is not qualitatively different from any other business in this regard.

Comment: @pojo-guy - except that how you differentiate yourself would be specific to video production.  I do believe startups could help, but I'm not sure that this is something that couldn't also fit here.